# How to prevent bulk row deletion operations?

Tags: postgresql, triggers, delete-row

I can prevent DELETE completely like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER prevent_multiple_row_del
BEFORE DELETE ON ALL
BEGIN
RAISE EXCEPTION 'Cant delete more than 1 row at a time';
END;
```

But how do I check if the delete operation will lead to deletion of multiple rows? Deletion is not a problem, as long as it's limited to a constant number (1 or 5 or 10, as long as it's not unlimited).

Alternatively, how do I allow deletions but prevent deletions of full tables?

Comment: Are you sure you are using Postgres? `raise_application_error` is an Oracle PL/SQL procedure.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Apologies for that, but yes I'm using psql. I wrote that piece of code as an example.

Answer (score 3):

A *before statement* trigger is too early to know the affected rows.

**As to full table deletes**, use an *after statement* trigger. All you'd have to do is select from the table and see whether there is some record left in it.

**As to deletes of up to n records**, this too would have to be determined *after statement*. You tagged your question PostgreSQL, but as a_horse_with_no_name pointed out your code is Oracle. In PostgreSQL you'd want to check `pg_affected_rows()` and in Oracle `SQL%ROWCOUNT`. I don't know whether PostgreSQL allows to check `pg_affected_rows()` in an after statement trigger. For Oracle, checking `SQL%ROWCOUNT` in an after statement trigger doesn't work. It's too early for this variable to check.

So at least for Oracle the trick is to have some custom counter to set to zero *before statement*, increase *after each row* and check *after statement*. I don't know precisely how to do that in PostgreSQL, but there certainly will be a way. In Oracle you'd use a compound trigger, i.e. a super trigger housing the individual triggers.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER prevent_multiple_row_del
FOR DELETE ON mytable COMPOUND TRIGGER
  v_count INTEGER := 0;

  AFTER EACH ROW IS
  BEGIN
    v_count := v_count + 1;
  END AFTER EACH ROW;

  AFTER STATEMENT IS
  BEGIN
    IF v_count > 1 THEN
      raise_application_error(-20000, 'Can''t delete more than 1 row at a time');
    END IF;
  END AFTER STATEMENT;

END prevent_multiple_row_del;
```

Comment: Apologies but yes, I'm using psql, I just wrote that piece of code as an example.